# Do something after a successful HTTP GET

Tags: angular, observable

I have the following function:

```
public getList(): Observable<T[]> {
    let url = this.baseUrl + this.type + 'list';
    return this.http.get<any>(url, {headers: this.headers })
        .retry(3)
        .map(response => response.list as T[],
          (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            this.toastrService.error('everything is broken', 'Major Error', {
              timeOut: 3000,
            });
            console.log(error.name);
          });
}
```

I want to add a toaster with `toasterService.success()` also after a successful Webservice call, but I can not figure out how to add this after `.map(response => response.list as T[]`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to subscribe to this method. Remember, you are using Observables. Hence you need observers.

You can do something like this:

```
public getList(): Observable<T[]> {
    let url = this.baseUrl + this.type + 'list';
    return this.http.get<any>(url, {headers: this.headers })
        .retry(3)
        .map(response => response.list as T[])
}

this.getList().subscribe((response)=>{
    //Handle your success here
},
(error)=>{
    //Handle Your Error here
});
```

Remember that you should use map function only to convert your response into a specific format. If you look closely, you are already returning the response in the beginning of that line.

All the code that you need to run on the success or error of your GET request, should be handled on the subscriber as I have mentioned above.

Your getList() method has done it's job by returning the data. Now it is the subscriber's job to handle it.

Apart from this, if your getList method sits in a service, then you need to inject the service in the constructor of your component by providing it in the component decorator.

And then instead of doing `this.getList().subscribe()`, you can do `this.yourServiceInstance.getList().subscribe()`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know I can handle the succes in the block after `.subscribe()`, but then I would have to implement the toast messages after every call of the `subscribe()`. I don't understand where to put the `this.getList().subscribe(.....)`  stuff, because of `this`. it is not meant to be in my service, but where should it be then? Thank you.

Comment: Subscribers should be in the component. You need to inject your toasterService in your component constructor. Please read this article on how to inject a service into a component. https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html

Comment: And you don't need to subscribe more than once. Whenever there is new data available from your GET, your success handler will be fired. Hence the word "Subscribe". You are subscribing to data changes from your service.

Comment: Assuming I have two list variables in different components that get their data from my `getList()`GET function, I would have to implement the error and success toast messages with both `.subscribe()` when assigning the data to the lists from the webservice, is that right?

Comment: Correct. In each component you need to have a subscriber

Comment: Otherwise you can subscribe to the getList method inside the service itself, and then inject the service in both components. Then you don't have to do multiple subscribes

Comment: Is it any bad to do the subscribe inside the service? Because it seems double work for me to implement exactly the same success/error handling for every subscribe call, I mean this can't really be true?

Comment: No it's not bad. You can use your service object inside each of your components to do whatever task you need. But usually, Observables are used because they can have multiple subscribers. That is the whole point. :)

Comment: Thank you for your kind help, I think I undestood the whole concept a little more now. Do you know if I could use Intercepter to invoke the toast messages?